# What is the role of the $ in the code, ls . | grep '.txt$'

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux and im learning from a website, and this came up in the grep part of a course

i tried running the same code but without the $ symbol and it displays the same output, so im wondering what the role of the $ is

Comment: Are you aware of how that parameter to grep works? (same question as jons, but with a hint how to arrive there on your own...)

Comment: To clarify, `grep` uses "regular expressions" (also known as "regex"), a way to specify patterns of text to mach against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grep` manual (run `man grep` in the terminal), you may find the following documentation regarding this:

```
Anchoring
   The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.
```

The intention in the use case you saw is clearly to ensure the filtered `.txt` filenames don't include extra characters at the end of the file extension.
As you can see here, for example:

```
$ ls  
file1.txt  file2.txtz

$ ls | grep '.txt'
file1.txt
file2.txtz

$ ls | grep '.txt$'
file1.txt
```

Also, have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124463).